# Shell scripting - replace every 5 commas with a newline

Tags: shell, unix

How can I replace every 5th comma in some input with a newline?

For example:

```
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15
```

becomes

```
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
```

Looking for a one-liner using something like `sed`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should work:

```
sed 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{4\}[^,]*\),/\1\n/g'
```

Example:

```
$ echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15" |
> sed 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{4\}[^,]*\),/\1\n/g'
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
```

Comment: Note that this doesn't work for me on OS X/Lion. I looked at solutions posted elsewhere for getting the carriage return on OS X and they didn't work for me on Lion.

Comment: BSD sed is a little different than GNU sed. Try this, it'll work with both variants (I tested on Lion and Slackware): `echo "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15" | sed -e 's/\(\([^,]*,\)\{4\}[^,]*\),/\1\'$'\n/g'` - https://cafenate.wordpress.com/2010/12/05/newlines-in-sed-on-mac/

Answer (score 1):

This expression will do.

```
sed 's/\(\([0-9]\+,\)\{4\}\)\([0-9]\+\),/\1\3\n/g'
```

http://ideone.com/d4Va2

Answer (score 1):

```
$ echo -n 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15 | xargs -d, printf '%d,%d,%d,%d,%d\n'
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted solution works, but is overly complicated.  Try:

```
sed ':d s/,/\n/5; P; D; Td'
```

Not all sed allow commands to be separated by semi-colons, so you may need a literal newline after each semi-colon.  Also, I'm not sure that all sed allow a label followed by a command, so a literal newline may be required before the s command.  In other words:

```
 sed ':d
s/,/\n/5
P
D
Td'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
nawk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i%5?",":"\n")}}' file3
```

test:

```
pearl.246> nawk -F, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){printf("%s%s",$i,i%5?",":"\n")}}' file3
1,2,3,4,5
6,7,8,9,10
11,12,13,14,15
pearl.247>
```